# Load various size images in a fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have 5-6 images with various sizes like width from 1000px to  1048px and height from 593px to 1736px. But its not loading small images. I tried to pass the width & height but its not working.

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/press/creating websies for NGOS.png" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Creating websites for NGOs" data-width="1048" data-height="593">
    <img src="images/press/creating websies for NGOS.png" style="border:0" alt="">
</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
        this.width  = $(this.element).data("width");
        this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
        }
});
```

So how do it. It will load as per the width & height passed from html. Any idea guys ?

Comment: I am doing it in my localhost...

Comment: then tell me how to get fancybx plugin,Do u belive on my programming ability?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Sorry for late reply...from here u can get the plugin http://fancybox.net/

Comment: @PratikJoshi now we made live you can check here http://firstplanet.in/about/feature.php/#myCarousel3

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle of it? Your example loads way to slow and we can try anything..

Comment: 1). what do you mean with `But its not loading small images`? 2). Do you want to display the images in their real size (not scaled down by fancybox)? if so you don't need to pass any `data-*` value. 3). Why are you using the same target image (`href`) as thumbnail (image's tag `src`) instead of edited/sacaled thumbnails? with such big images, you are adding an overhead to your page load. Use a small image for the `<img>` and target the big image within the `href` attribute of your `<a>` tag.

Comment: Hey small images its loading fine clearly...but with big images i want to show the popup with scroll bar & clear...got it

Comment: Can you run `jQuery('#myCarousel3')` in console? Apparently non of your JS files are loaded.
https://gist.github.com/pekhee/14cb562219ed6ef84118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is the context of `this` being lost.

Whenever we use `this` in a function, the context of `this` takes that function.

**So we can assign it early : `var $this = $(this);`**

---

Edit: Perhaps `this.element` is a fancybox way to get the element, I don't know, if so, I'm wrong. Nontheless, here's what we can do , if you want to make use of those `data` height and width attributes:

```
$('a.fancybox').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* stop the default anchor click */

    var $this = $(this); /* register this */
    $.fancybox({
        'content': $this.html(), /* the image in the markup */
        'width': $this.attr("data-width"),
        'height': $this.attr("data-height"),
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'autoSize': false
    });

});
```

Try this out **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/a2Jh9/)**

---

Also **some CSS** will help keep the `fancybox` frame from scrolling ( for this direct image usage )

```
.fancybox-inner img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rob its worked really well ...thnx for ur time & effort

Answer (score 3):

### The Problem

Your current URL is

```
http://firstplanet.in/about/feature.php/
```

and your images are linked to

```
images/press/commitment to unemployment.png
```

which gets expanded to

```
http://firstplanet.in/about/feature.php/images/press/creating%20websies%20for%20NGOS.png
```

change your image links to

```
/about/images/press/commitment to unemployment.png
```

to get them working.

### More Info

Read this article [on relative URLs](http://www.colliope.com/learn/misc/relurls.shtml). Here is an excerpt.

#### Not prepending a `/`

> If the image has the same host and the same path as the base document:
>
> ```
> http://www.colliope.com/birdpics/owl/pic01.jpg
> http://www.colliope.com/birdpics/owl/page.html
> ```
>
> We would write `< img src="pic01.jpg" >`

#### Prepending a `/`

> If the image has the same host but a different path:
>
> ```
> http://www.colliope.com/gifs/groovy14/button.gif
> http://www.colliope.com/birdpics/owl/page.html
> ```
>
> We would write `< img src="/gifs/groovy14/button.gif" >`

Comment: @RIA Dev none of your JS files are loaded too, check if they have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.fancybox("<img src='images/press/creating_websies_for_NGOS.png' style='border:0'>");
```

Comment: @HAT I have several images as u seen in the link...but i have to click the images to show the images in a big pop up

Comment: No its not working out for me. The image is opening separately with full link not in a popup

Comment: its saying the 'requested content can not be loaded.' I copied your code but its not loading.....i dont know whats the problem

Comment: If you do in your local, i can not debug for you. :(

Comment: Hey i used your same code...i dont know wats the problem...is jquery version matters ?